# How to use composite component

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm create `mycomponent.xhtml` in the root of `Web Pages` directory. In `mycomponent.xhtml` i describe some composite component

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <composite:interface/>
    <composite:implementation>
        ...
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Now i'm creating facelet `index.html` in the root of `Web Pages` directory. But i cannot use `mycomponent`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:mycomp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
         <mycomp:mycomponent/>      <!--Error, the component library composite does not contain mycomponent-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composite component page (mycomponemt.xhtml) that you placed at the root **must be located at `/resources/mycomp` folder**: see [composite components documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) for details.

You can find a kickoff example in [Oracle's Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html). Another one can be found in our [composite component tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info).

Comment: Another one can be found in our tag wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info